# Guard Malloc on Linux

Tags: c, debugging, malloc

Is there a Linux counterpart for [Guard Malloc](https://www.unix.com/man-page/All/3/guardmalloc/) for Mac OS? As far as I know, this one only works on OSX.

In other words, I need a library for debugging malloc with features such as `MALLOC_MAXIMUM_VM` which simulates out of memory cases, etc..

Comment: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)? .....

Comment: Thanks, does it provide an option similar to MALLOC_MAXIMUM_VM?

Comment: Note that a standard reason for closing questions as off-topic on SO is "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."  This qualifies pretty accurately.